# nested selectors with & (amperstand) are not working

Tags: sass, jsx

I have the following code

```
.myclass {
  &::-webkit-etc {...}
  &::-moz-etc {...}
}
```

the properties (`...`) are the same for both selectors so I did

```
.myclass {
  &::-webkit-etc,
  &::-moz-etc {...}
}
```

the first version works fine but for some reason the second one doesn't.

I'm using the scss in my JSX like this

```
import css from './styles.scss'

...

<div className={css.myclass}>...
```

Comment: It would help if you added a few more details, such as the specific style properties you are trying to add, or some html markup.